# Parse comma seperated string into columns in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, string

I was working with an SQL table and came across a column looking like this :

| columnName |
| --- |
| attr1=val1a; attr2=val2a; attr3=val3a; attr4=val4a |
| attr1=val1b; attr5=val5b; attr3=val3b; attr6=val6b |

It is of type = string. I want to split this one column into multiple columns like :

| attr1 | attr2 | attr3 | attr4 | attr5 | attr6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| val1a | val2a | val3a | val4a | Null | Null |
| val1b | Null | val3b | Null | val5b | val6b |

Can someone help me find a way to do this in SQL please.

Thanks in advance!

Edit : I am using MySQL

Comment: Could you tag with your engine - SQL Server, Oracle, MariaDB, etc..

Comment: @gotqn I am using MySQL. Sorry for the missing tag.

Comment: What is precise MySQL version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE test
SELECT 'attr1=val1a; attr2=val2a; attr3=val3a; attr4=val4a' columnName
  UNION ALL
SELECT 'attr1=val1b; attr5=val5b; attr3=val3b; attr6=val6b'
```

```
SELECT columnName,
       as_json->>'$.attr1' attr1,
       as_json->>'$.attr2' attr2,
       as_json->>'$.attr3' attr3,
       as_json->>'$.attr4' attr4,
       as_json->>'$.attr5' attr5,
       as_json->>'$.attr6' attr6 
FROM (
    SELECT columnName,
           CONCAT('{"', REPLACE(REPLACE(columnName, '=', '":"'), '; ', '","') , '"}') as_json
    FROM test
    ) to_json
```

| columnName | attr1 | attr2 | attr3 | attr4 | attr5 | attr6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| attr1=val1a; attr2=val2a; attr3=val3a; attr4=val4a | val1a | val2a | val3a | val4a | *null* | *null* |
| attr1=val1b; attr5=val5b; attr3=val3b; attr6=val6b | val1b | *null* | val3b | *null* | val5b | val6b |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qqhr55FB)